# Java Application to install APK on android

Tags: java, android, adb

I am trying to make a simple application in Java to install an APK on android devices connected via USB.  Using ABD manually then everything works fine, but I wanted to give a simple single button click install option within my application, but for some reason the code isnt working:

```
    try {
        abdsourcesync = apkpath;
        progress.setString("sync in progress");
        System.out.println("Starting Sync via adb with command " + "adb"
                + " install -r " + apkpath);

        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "adb" + " install -r " + apkpath);
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                process.getInputStream());
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
        scanner.close();
        int exitCode = process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Process returned: " + exitCode);
```

The process exits with a status of 141 but no other errors that I can see, but when I look on the tablet the .APK has not installed.  I have checked to make sure there is space on the device which is rooted and supports third party apps etc, so I am certain the issue is with my java and not the android device (as I said if I run the ADB install -r myself from terminal then all works fine).

I have searched around stackoverflow but have only found threads on installing an APK from within an Android application, not from a desktop Java application.

Thanks for the help;

EDIT:  New code looks like this now with ProcessBuilder managing the adb call:

```
        try {
            abdsourcesync = apkpath;
            progress.setString("sync in progress");
            System.out.println("Starting Sync via adb with command " + "adb"
                    + " install -r " + apkpath);

            ProcessBuilder apksync = new ProcessBuilder("adb",  " install -r ",  apkpath);

            apksync = apksync.redirectErrorStream(true);
/*          Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                    "adb" + " install -r " + apkpath);*/
            Process process = apksync.start();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(
                    process.getInputStream());
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(reader);
            scanner.close();
            int exitCode = process.waitFor();
            System.out.println("Process returned: " + exitCode);
```

The apk sync just fails straight away with a status of 1 being returned to the console.

If I manually specify the apk location

```
ProcessBuilder apksync = new ProcessBuilder("adb","install","/home/geeky/Desktop/1.apk");
```

then I get the same error as the original code, the process returns status 141 and after a period of time the sync process completes but the .apk isnt available on the table.  I also get the same result if I try with an APK much smaller than my 700mb app (as in a 500kb .apk gives the same results).

EDIT3:  I also tried changing the command to push the apk and it works without error, the apk will push to /mnt/sdcard/test/1.apk without issue.

Andy

Comment: Anyone able to offer some help on this issue?

Answer (score 1):

i guess it is because your java application not being able to resolve the adb binary. try adding the adb binary in your environment variable so that it is accessible from anywhere.

try this:

```
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd","arg1");
pb = pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
    Process proc = pb.start();
    InputStream is = proc.getInputStream();
```

Comment: i get it .... use the processbuilder instead of the runtime.exec()

ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("adb", "arg1",);

arguments can't be passed to runtime.exec(). it can just execute a single program. processbuilder is handy in this case i suppose. This is worth giving a try!

Comment: Thank you, nearly there I think but I am getting the following exception when i try to run the above code: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb install -r /home/geeky/Desktop/1.apk": error=2, No such file or directory
 at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)

Comment: do this :
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("adb","install","/home/geeky/Desktop/1.apk");

the D on your desktop is uppercase ...unix is case sensitive i hope the path is correct. :D

Comment: Thanks, the file path was being passed correctly but i had forgotten to change the string to , instead of + to spilt the args.  I am now just getting an error process returned 1. I have edited the main post to reflect my new code if that helps.

Comment: Any other ideas why this isn't working for me with the new code?

Comment: Failed straight away, I have tried -d, -s and -r independently and get the same result each time.